# I have a windows authenticated HTML page hosted on IIS. How to get LoginID using C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I have created a sample `html` page and hosted it on `IIS`. I have enabled `windows authentication`. Now what I want to do is whenever I run the application, the  `Login ID` entered by the user to be stored in `database` (I have already created a `web service` to send data to my `database`). I just want know the `command` to store the `Login ID` in a variable. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WindowsIdentity yourUserIdentity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

Now you can get the User name by the following property of the [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object yourUserIdentity.

```
yourUserIdentity.Name
```

Comment: My low reputation isn't allowing me to do this :(

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the username:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Here is an explanation on how it works:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows authentication you can use this to get the LoginID

```
string user = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```